# Wavedec in matlab returns length with sum greater than the original length of signal

Tags: arrays, matlab, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I was doing multilevel wavelet decomposition for a signal 'price1' by using

```
 [c1, l] = wavedec(price1, 3, 'db4');
```

The size of price1 was:

```
size(price1) =

   240     1
```

And the size of wavelet decomposition obtained i.e length of l is:

```
l =

    36
    36
    65
   123
   240
```

I am a beginner, and I think the size should be:

```
l =

    30
    30
    60
   120
   240
```

I am not able to understand why is the size not half of the signal size? Is this some sort of padding happening internally? And I would want the size to be half like [30; 30; 60; 120; 240]. What can I do to achieve it?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not considering the length of mother wavelet, which will change the length of signal after convolution.

`db4` has the length of `8`,

```
 a = randi(10,[240 1]);
 [c1, l] = wavedec(a, 3, 'db4');

l =
36
36
65
123
240
```

But for example `db8` has the length of `16`

```
[c1, l] = wavedec(a, 3, 'db8');

l =
43
43
71
127
240
```

You can have access to wavelet functions like this,

```
[LoD,HiD,LoR,HiR] = wfilters('db8');
```